# Renting a car in the USA with a driver's licence issued by another country than the passport

Tags: usa, passports, car-rentals, driving-licenses

Is it required, when renting a car in the US, that the country issuing the driver's license is the same as the passport's one?

Both are from a EU country, if that matters (passport is French and driver's license is Polish).

**Clarification** after a comment: nationality is French, country of residence is France, passport is French and driving license is Polish.

**UPDATE**: I looked up some rental companies requirements and it would seem that it does matter:

[Dollar](https://www.dollar.com/AboutUs/GeneralPolicies.aspx)

> (6) a foreign driver’s license* issued by the country of residence of
>   the renter and additional drivers
>
> (...)
>
> If the foreign issued driver’s license is from a country where
>   “permanent” or “non-expiring” driver’s license are issued, the renter
>   and any additional drivers will also be required to show their
>   passport, visa, or other current U.S. issued documentation at the
>   beginning of their rental authorizing the renter or driver to be
>   present in the USA at the time of rental.

[AVIS](https://www.avis.com/en/customer-service/faqs/usa/requirement-for-renting)

> A license issued by a country that participated in the 1949 Geneva
>   convention on Road Traffic or the 1943 Convention on the Regulation of
>   Inter-American Automobile Traffic.
>
> Additionally, if you intend to rent outside of your home country, Avis
>   may require that you present a valid passport, as  secondary form of
>   identification at the time of your check-out.

[HERTZ](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/reservation/reviewmodifycancel/templates/rentalTerms.jsp?KEYWORD=LICENSE&EOAG=LAX) (I saw the English version once, then it switched to French for good - translation below)

> Lors de la prise en charge du véhicule, vous devrez présenter un
>   permis de conduire en cours de validité délivré dans votre pays de
>   résidence
>
> When taking over the vehicle, you must present a valid driving license
>   issued in your country of residence

**FINAL UPDATE**: I ended up not being asked for anything (including a driver's license) because I am a Gold member with HERTZ (which I actually forgot, my last reting with HERTZ was years ago).
Even without that I indeed highly doubt that they would have applied the "driver's license issued in country of residence" rule.

Comment: A Passport does not have to be for the country of residence. Generally it is an indication of nationality or citizenship. Your case was specific, but you could have claimed residency of Poland without a Polish passport. This is an EU possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not required.  There are millions of people in the world in this situation, and rental car companies would not want to refuse their business.

Comment: Please see my update with teh rental car companies statements on driver's licenses requirements. Some (Dollar, HERTZ) are clear (license must be from country of residence), while others (AVIS) are less explicit.

Comment: @WoJ Do you reside outside Poland?  Your question asks whether the license must be from the country of citizenship, and then you quote some terms that say the license must be from your country of residence.  Residence and citizenship are not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify that in the question (this is not me but it does not matter). Nationality is French, country of residence is France, passport is French and driving license is Polish.

Comment: @WoJ I suspect that it would be possible to use a Polish license by pointing out that EU rules allow a resident of France to continue with a Polish license as long as the Polish license remains valid.  But to be on the safe side, I would also consider renting from Avis or another company that does not mention "country of residence" in its requirements.

Comment: @WoJ unless you're planning on going living in Poland any time soon, you can swap your Polish licence for a French one here https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Le-ministere/Prefectures When your licence expires you'll have to retake your test in France. https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-renewal-exchange/france/index_en.htm

Comment: @WoJ From personal experience renting in the US, as long as you have a credit card and something that looks like a valid driver's license, you'll have zero issues renting a car.  Residency, visas, passports etc are not really the agency's concern.

Comment: @jpatokal that's my sense, too, but I've never tried to rent a car in the US with a foreign license, much less one that was issued by a country other than the one I lived in.

Comment: @phoog I have, but it never came up, since I was never asked for anything besides my drivers' license.  Also, while citizenship can be demonstrated easily enough with a passport, how do you even prove "residency"?

Comment: @jpatokal every time I rent a car, they ask for my address.  It seems to me that giving an address where you don't actually live is probably not a good idea.